# How to redirect active class to dropdown submenu?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, navbar, dropdown

I have created a navbar with dropdown. Navigating works quite well. And the "active" class can be transferred without problems, but not to the "li" elements of the dropdown. All active "li" are underlined with border-bottom. If I navigate to "li" element "dropdown" it will be underlined, but not the selected "li" item in dropdown. What am I doing wrong?

Here is my index.html

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-
    toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <section class="layout">
                    <div class="branding">
                        <a href="/"><img src="images/header/app_fh_logo.png" 
      alt="App logo"></a>
                    </div><!--branding-->
                </section><!--layout-->
            </div><!--navbar-header-->
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li alt="standard"><a href="/"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-
      home"></span>Startseite</a>
                </li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span>Messenger<b class="caret">
    </b></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="/profile"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-
    user"></span>Konto</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/about"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-
    info-sign"></span>Über</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-
    out"></span>Abmelden</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div><!-- navbar collapse -->
    </nav>
```

here is js

```
  $(".nav a").filter(function () {
        return this.href == location.href
    }).parent().addClass("active").siblings().removeClass("active");

    $("li").click(function () {
        // remove classes from all
        $("li").removeClass("active");
        // add class to the one we clicked
        $(this).addClass("active");
    });
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $("li").click(function () {
   $("li").each(function(index, ele) {
        $(ele).removeClass("active");

    });
        $(this).addClass("active");
    });
```

use jquery each function inside li click function to remove all active classes

Comment: Still the same result. active is not added to the <li> element of dropdown